# Pass dictionary keys into function

Tags: python, json, function, dictionary

I want to write a function that accesses a dictionary key and renames it if the key exists. For example:

```
def json_rename(json_input, json_output, to_replace):
    json_output = []
    
    for j in json_input:
        try:
            j["key1"][0]["key_2"] = j["key1"][0].pop(to_replace)
            json.output.append(j)
        except:
            json.output.append(j)
   
    return json_output
```

`j["key1"][0]["key_2"]` could be any combination of keys, but how do I pass those as arguments?

Comment: You can pass it as a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass in a list that represents the "path" of your target key. For example:

```py
import contextlib

def rename_key(json_input, path, new_key):
    for j in json_input:
        with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
            for p in path[:-1]:
                j = j[p]
            j[new_key] = j[path[-1]]
            del j[path[-1]]

rename_key(json_input, ['key1', 0, 'key2'], 'New Key 2')
rename_key(json_input, ['key3', 'key4', 1, 'key5'], 'New Key 5')
```

Comment: The problem is that ["key1"][0] are supposed to be dynamic because the json file is quite complex so the path changes. So I may also have to change the key for ["key3"]["key4"][1]["key_5"].

Comment: I see. Updated to address your comment.